# Should gapi.client fail gracefully if the service is unavailable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints

### Should gapi.client fail gracefully if the service is unavailable for any reason?

I'm doing some tests with Google Endpoints and a Javascript client that uses AngularJS.

#### The following code injects the Endpoint library into Angular:

```
<script>
    function apiCallback() {
      console.log('test');
      var apisToLoad = 1; // must match number of calls to gapi.client.load()
      var gCallback = function () {
        if (--apisToLoad == 0) {
          //Manual bootstraping of the application
          var $injector = angular.bootstrap(document, ['anatelFront']);
        }
      };
      gapi.client.load('anatel', 'v1', gCallback, '//localhost:8080/_ah/api');
    }
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=apiCallback"></script>
```

#### The Main Controller is coded as following:

```
anatelFront.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
  function ($scope) {

    $scope.filter = 0;
    try {
      gapi.client.anatel.directors.listDirectors({'filter':
        $scope.filter}).execute(function(resp){
        if (resp.queryResult){
          $scope.directors = angular.fromJson(resp.queryResult);
          console.log($scope.directors);
        }

      });
    }
    catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
}]);
```

I'm running GAE locally (Python on Linux) and when I shutdown the dev server process, the Angular Controller breaks and the Browser returns a Runtime error, therefore breaking the rendering of the Angular controller. Angular is the latest version.

#### The error that shows at the browser console:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/static/proxy.html?jsh=m%3Y1Mqg net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
    zk 
    c 
    (anonymous function) 
    f
```

Should gapi.client fail gracefully?

Am I doing something wrong or not doing something I should, like checking if the service is available before executing gapi.client?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gapi.client.load() doesn't provide an error callback as, far as I know. A $timeout call is probably the best way to deal with this. Just before calling gapi.client.load(), set a $timeout that outputs an error after, say 5 or 10 seconds (whatever you think is reasonable). Then clear the $timeout if the gapi.client.load() is successful, so no error is outputted.